# Extract Nested Fields in KQL

Tags: kql

How can I extract the nested fields (Marked in Yellow)?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

dynamic object accessors are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors

for example - the following will return a single table with a single column and a single record, whose value is `world`

```
print d = dynamic([{"hello":"world"},{"foo":"bar"}])
| project d[0].hello
```

Comment: @Gary, if this answers your question, please accept the answer :)  If you're still missing some info, please add a comment specifying what's missing.